# $H=[h_1, h_2, \cdots, h_n]$, $h_i\in \mathbb{C}^m, m>n$. prove the orthogonal complement problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$H=[h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_n]$, where $h_i\in \mathbb{C}^m, m>n$. Let $Q_i$ be the matrix whose columns are formed by the orthonormal bases of the orthogonal complement of the subspace spaned by $\{h_1,h_2,h_{i-1},h_{i+1},\cdots,h_n\}$.

prove that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n h_ih_i^H\, Q_iQ_i^H=\alpha I
$$

for some $\alpha$.

I'm bogged down with this problem for quite a while, thanks at first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
H=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
Q_1Q_1^T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
\quad
Q_2Q_2^T=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I can't see any way how to (non-trivially) combine the two projectors in order to obtain a scalar matrix.

EDIT: The statement remains generally not true since
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n h_ih_i^HQ_iQ_i^H
$$
is a sum of $n$ rank-one matrices, which cannot sum to a rank $m$ matrix if $m>n$.

Comment: @Pavel: I'm sorry, I have updated the question(typos are corrected).

Comment: @Maple I've updated the answer. The statement is still not true (now for more clear reasons).